# Observable chain repeating itself

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I have a chain of observables which follow this logic: getStyles() --> getPrices()

For every config.id in configs, _APIService.getStyleByID() returns a style Object called "res", this style Object is passed to getLease() where a price is appended to it and is then pushed an array called "garage"

```
  getStyles(configs: any) {
      configs.forEach(config => {
           this._APIService.getStyleByID(config.id).subscribe(
                res => {
                    res.config = config;
                    this.getLease(res);
                }
           );
    });

  }

  getLease(style: any): void {
      this._priceService.getPrice().subscribe(
        price => {
            style.price = price;
            this.garage.push(style);
            console.log(this.garage);
        });
  }


}
```

The issue I am experiencing is that there is a loop being done on _APIService.getStyleByID. How do I fix my Service method to only be called once per config? (it recurses over the the configs array two or three times more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By appending `take(1)` before `subscribe`, this fixed my issue.